# The "or", (|) in BNF Grammar

Tags: python, bnf

I can't seem to fully understand the application of the "or" in BNF Grammar which is denoted by the vertical bar symbol (|). A good example of what gets me confused is the description of string literals in The Python Language Reference. (I've deleted part of the description which is irrelevant to the question):

```
stringliteral   ::=  [stringprefix](shortstring | longstring)
shortstring     ::=  "'" shortstringitem* "'" | '"' shortstringitem* '"'
shortstringitem ::=  shortstringchar | stringescapeseq
shortstringchar ::=  <any source character except "\" or newline or the quote>
stringescapeseq ::=  "\" <any source character>
```

So, the way I understand the description of `<shortstringitem>` is that it can be `<shortstringchar>` OR `<stringecapeseq>`. Does this mean it cannot be both at the same time? If I am not mistaken a single string may contain both at the same time... (For clarity `<shortstingchar>` as I understand it is the text of my string)

Thank you.

Searched the web, including stackoverflow and watched explanatory videos but all seem to describe the "or" with something like:

`<letter> ::= A|B|C|D|E...Y|Z.`

Without going in too deep with the examples... Unfortunately this does not answer my question.

Comment: What would it mean for `shortstringitem` to be both at the same time? When parsing a concrete string, you have to decide which a particular sequence of characters represents. When generating a string, you have to pick which alternative you will generate a substring for.

Comment: `Does this mean it cannot be both at the same time?` Yes. `If I am not mistaken a single string may contain both at the same time` Yes. A string can contain both but any given `shortstringitem` can only take on _one_ of the alternatives.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*One* `shortstringitem` can only be one or the other. But a `shortstring` can consist of *multiple* `shortstringitem`s, each of which is "expanded" independently.

Consider `'x\n'`, for example, which you could parse as

```
'x\n' -> stringliteral
      -> shortstring
      -> "'"  shortstringitem shortstringitem "'"
      -> "'" shortstringchar stringescapeseq "'"
      -> "'" 'x' '\' 'n' "'"
```

The first `shortstringitem` is recognized as a `shortstringchar`, the second as a `stringescapeseq`.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. I understand now. It seems that I didn't take in to account the “*” character following <shortstingitem>. It all makes sense now. Once again, thank you!